# Case Expression on a created column using Microsoft SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

Within a view I put put together a select statement within a case and delcared it as a column. The column name is 'IR2'

How can I case off of the column 'IR2'?

I end up getting an error which says 'Invalid Column Name 'IR2'.

What are my work around options?

```
case when r.ana = 'nh3' and r.serv='energy' and exists( select 1 from results x where x.no=r.no and x.ana='nh3' and x.sa='rejected' and x.serv <> 'energy')
then '*' else r.sa end as IR2,

CASE IR2 WHEN 'Released' then
 '' 
 ELSE
 '*' 
 END AS IR
```

Comment: You cannot use the alias IR2 in the select clause

Answer (score 1, accepted):

CTE would be the best choice. If you want to continue with current statement, you need to put a copy of the case statement in other case statement. Very messy code.

```sql
SELECT
case when r.ana = 'nh3' and r.serv='energy' and 
exists( select 1 from results x where x.no=r.no and x.ana='nh3' and x.sa='rejected' and x.serv <> 'energy')
then '*' else r.sa end as IR2,

CASE 
    (case when r.ana = 'nh3' and r.serv='energy' 
        and exists( select 1 from results x where x.no=r.no and x.ana='nh3' and x.sa='rejected' and x.serv <> 'energy') 
        then '*' else r.sa end)
WHEN 'Released' then
    '' 
ELSE
    '*' 
END AS IR
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use a subquery or CTE.  But another fun way in SQL Server is using `outer apply`:

```
select v.IR2,
       (case IR2 when 'Released' then '' else '*' end) as ir
from . . . outer apply
     (values (case when r.ana = 'nh3' and r.serv='energy' and
                        exists( select 1 from results x where x.no=r.no and x.ana='nh3' and x.sa='rejected' and x.serv <> 'energy')
                   then '*' else r.sa
              end)
     ) v(IR2)
```

Comment: IR2 is not a field but an alias in the query. The alias can only be used in the `order by` clause, not elsewhere in the select.

Comment: @sle1306 . . . Huh?  `IR2` is defined in the `FROM` clause using `OUTER APPLY`.  Your comment is wrong, and why it would get upvoted I have no idea.

Comment: I was taking about the original query in the question, not about the one in your answer.

Comment: @sle1306 . . . Then the comment should go on the *question* not the *answer*.